# Is it possible to trigger a browser's event handlers without input devices?

Tags: javascript, browser, webkit, dom-events

Is it possible to trigger a browsers event handlers without input devices? Can someone with a modified browser or any other method trigger an event handler in a page they requested without physical input devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can use automated web browsing tools, like the iMacros add-on for Firefox or WebDriver for Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can use the respective name of the event and invoke it, for example, `DOMElement`'s `onclick` event handler:

```
element.onclick(); //invokes all of the attached onclick handlers
```